# Data from database always returns Empty Array while using Room Library

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room, mvp

I want ask about my code. Error does not show when I insert data in the database, but when I try to getAll I just get empty array.
I don't know where it goes wrong. I hope someone can give me a solution to this problem.

This is the first time I'm using the Room Library.

This is my interface for the Dao:

```
@Dao
interface SampleDao {
@Query("SELECT * from Sample")
fun getAll():Single<List<Sample>>

@Insert
fun insertSampel(sample:Sample)
```

This is my singletonDB:

```
@Database (entities = [Sample::class], version = 1)
abstract class SingletonDB : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun sampleDao():SampleDao

companion object {
    private var INSTANCE:SingletonDB? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context):SingletonDB?{
        if (INSTANCE == null){
            synchronized(SingletonDB::class){
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                        SingletonDB::class.java, "db")
                        .build()
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE!!
    }

    fun destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null
    }

}
```

This is the getAllData method from the room database:

```
  override fun getAll() {
    mDB.sampleDao().getAll()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(object : SingleObserver<List<Sample>> {
                override fun onSuccess(t: List<Sample>) {
                    Log.i(TAG, t.toString())
                }

                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {

                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    Log.i(TAG, e.message)
                }
            })
}
```

This code is used to insert data in database:

```
override fun insertSampel(id: Int, name: String, age: Int) {
    val sample = Sample(id, name, age)
    Completable.fromAction {
        Thread {
            Runnable {
                mDB.sampleDao().insertSampel(sample)
            }
        }
    }.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(
                    object : CompletableObserver {
                        override fun onComplete() {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Complete")
                        }

                        override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {

                        }

                        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                            Log.i(TAG, e.message)
                        }
                    }
            )
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have you debugged the origin of the issue?

You should check if your `INSERT` is working correctly before thinking the error is the `QUERY` (get)

As you are using Rx already, try to change your insertion code to this:

```
val sample = Sample(id, name, age)

Completable.fromAction(() -> mDB.sampleDao()
                .insertSampel(sample)) // By the way there's a typo here :)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // If you want to observe
                .subscribe(/* Handle the result and/or error */);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, after see your answer I know the problem about my code.
The problem in function insertSample where I user thread and runnable. I not need both of them coz I use rxjava.

Comment: Exactly that's what I mean since you already used Rx you _should_ do it like this :). Glad I could help you out.